# Unable to retrieve request/session data in Orbeon proxy-portlet

Tags: orbeon

I am running Orbeon 4.0 Beta 2 and unable to retrieve any request or session data in my forms using proxy-portlet in Liferay.

I've tried the following elements:

```
xxf:get-request-parameter('myParameter')
xxf:get-session-attribute('myAttribute', 'text/plain')
```

These two methods work when I'm using the form straight from Orbeon Form Runner (`http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/test-app/test-form/new?myParameter=foo`).

I have a Tomcat servlet filter in Orbeon servlet that sets a value to 'myAttribute' in every request. The url I'm using in Liferay is `http://localhost:8080/liferay/orbeon-form?myParameter=foo`

Furthermore I'm having trouble getting request headers in forms using (tested in Orbeon form runner and Liferay proxy-portlet)

```
xxf:get-request-header('OAM_REMOTE_USER')
```

Here is my properties-local.xml:

```
 <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri" value="http://localhost:8080/orbeon"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.method" value="header"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.authentication.header.username" value="OAM_REMOTE_USER"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.forward-submission-headers" value="OAM_REMOTE_USER"/>
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.http.forward-headers" value="OAM_REMOTE_USER"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Orbeon Forms 4.1 has support for forwarding request parameters and headers via a configuration of the proxy portlet. This was not possible prior to 4.1. See [the issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/886) and [doc](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/form-runner-proxy-portlet-guide#TOC-Configuring-header-and-URL-parameter-forwarding).

Comment: I need to get the browser default session information. How can I get the session information. I am running orbeon proxy portlet? The following link has my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582667/how-to-get-the-browser-session-information-in-orbeon. Need some  suggestion OR Help?